# react-native open specific screen on fcm notification click

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have searched on stack overflow haven't found anything.

This is how handling my on click

```
export const App = () => {
  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    const {data} = remoteMessage;
    if (data.action == 'open_map') {
      navigate('RouteMap', {data: data.eventsteamID});
    }
    if (data.action == 'open_home') {
      navigate('MainNavigator');
    }
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  });
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <LocationProvider>
        <AuthProvider>
          <RootNavigator />
        </AuthProvider>
      </LocationProvider>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};
```

i have created this service since navigation is not available before RootNavigator is attached

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const isMountedRef = React.createRef();

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (isMountedRef.current && navigationRef.current) {
    navigationRef.current.navigate(name, params);
  } else {
    console.log('Navigation Failed!');
  }
}
```

any one have solution.

this is my fcm response

[image: This is my fcm response]

EDIT:=> Same code work on android